# Magento 1.9 Suddenly will not accept an SKU starting with a letter

Tags: magento-1.9, sku

I'm currently running a staging copy of a live Magento 1.9 site. On this staging site I have noticed that if I attempt to add a new product with an SKU that begins with a letter (character between A-Z) (e.g. HOS2019), I get an error of

> Please enter a valid number in this field.

If I begin the `SKU` with a number, the product is accepted and saved with no issue.

The live copy of this site accepts a product a letter at the beginning of the `SKU` with no issue, so I know something is not quite right with this staging copy of the site.

I was just wondering if anyone had ever come across a problem such as this, and what code I could possibly look at to try and resolve this - or indeed what code I could compare with the live version of this site to try and find the fault.

Many thanks for any light anyone can shed on this.

Comment: Maybe you've got an input validation set on the SKU attribute at Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is accepted to leave thanks here, but thank you Christoph for pointing me in this obvious direction - this solved my issue and I feel like a twonk! And also thanks to Raj for editing my scruffy text.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Product attributes (Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes) can have validation options set.

In your case "Input Validation for Store Owner" says "Integer". Change it to "None" or "Letters (a-z, A-Z) or Numbers (0-9)" in order to be able to set SKUs the way you want.

[image: Edit Product Attribute "SKU" screen]